# How do you cancel someone's persistent cookie if their membership is no longer valid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, asp.net-membership

I'm designing a small ASP.NET MVC site for a club. Generally, I want users to be able to stay logged in, but what happens if a user's membership has lapsed? Is there any way to "de-authorize" them so that next time they try to view a page, it redirects them to a page telling them their membership has lapsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the timeout defined for the authentication cookie is hit it will no longer be valid and users will automatically be redirected to the login page. If you want to sign them out automatically under some circumstances you could simply:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Comment: Thanks, Darin. Relying on timeout alone would not be an ideal solution because I'd like to leave users logged in for several days at least under normal circumstances. As for the `SignOut()` method, I'm familiar with that (that's what happens when the LogOut page is requested), but I'm thinking that to properly maintain security, I would need to check a user for valid credentials inside every method of every controller. This pretty means I'd get no benefit from the built-in authorization.

Comment: @DanM, how about doing this in an action filter so that you don't have to repeat it on each action?

Comment: Darin, I haven't worked with action filters before, but I will look into this. Thanks.

Comment: An ActionFilter turned out to be the right solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make the expiration of the authentication cookie, the number of days that you want, or their membership expiration date, whichever is sooner, then you get the benefit of getting handled automatically

Comment: ...At login you would just have to use the FormsAuthenticationTicket, to set the cookie manually, instead of using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie

Comment: At the moment, there is no specification in the database for member expiration. The business rule is basically that non-paying members eventually get marked as inactive, but it's a manual process. In any case, +1 for a clever idea, and I could see adding an expiration date as a new feature.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the user's information from the cookie, you could add a check to see if their membership has lapsed and redirect them to that page.

Comment: Briguy, but I don't have any code where I actually check the cookie. I believe this all done automatically by ASP.NET. Is there any way I can override the usual behavior and add this check?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET, so I'm not sure.  I would think there would be a way to add a security filter that runs before showing each page in your application, but I don't know how to go about setting that up.