# How do you disable a User When Using ASP Forms Persistent Cookie/Ticket?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I'm using the Forms Auth and ASP Universal Membership Provider in an MVC 3 Site.  We're persisting the cookie for user convenience.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true)
```

When we disable a user in the Membership provider like this:

```
memUser.IsApproved = model.IsActive;
provider.UpdateUser(memUser);
```

if they have the cookie they can still get in to the site.    This is similar to what is described in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825273/how-do-you-cancel-someones-persistent-cookie-if-their-membership-is-no-longer-v

We use Authorize attributes on our controllers, and I know that that is technically more Authorize than Authentication.  But the certainly overloap so I'm trying to figure out what is the best MVC way to do a check that the user is not actually disabled?  Custom AuthorizeAttribute that checks the user against the membership database?  An obvious setting/method I'm missing with Forms auth to invalidate the ticket?

**Update:**

Here’s basically what I'm going with – we use a custom permission denied page which we we use to better inform user that they don’t have rights vs. they’re not logged in.  And I added the IsApproved check.  AuthorizeCore gets called when you put the attribute on a Controller or Action and if it returns false HandleUnauthorizedRequest is called.

```
public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !Membership.GetUser(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).IsApproved)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

            // in the case that the user was authenticated, meaning he has a ticket, 
            // but is no longer approved we need to sign him out 
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
        else
        {
            var permDeniedRouteVals = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { { "controller", "MyErrorController" }, { "action", "MyPermissionDeniedAction" }, { "area", null } };
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(permDeniedRouteVals);
        }
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // since persisting ticket,
        // adding this check for the case that the user is not active in the database any more
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) && Membership.GetUser(httpContext.User.Identity.Name).IsApproved; 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[CustomAuthorization()]
public class MyController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're going to have to check the database regardless, the only question is how you want to do that.  Yes, you could create a custom authorize attribute, or you could write some code for the OnAuthorize override in ControllerBase, or you could do it in Application_AuthenticateRequest.. lots of ways you could do it, depends on what works best for you.

The best way, of course, would be to not use a persistent ticket if this is an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much always use Roles and a RolesProvider, even if there is just one role named "Login" - in part for this issue. This way, your `Authorize` attributes might look something like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Login")]
```

Where `Login` represents a basic 'Role' that all "active" accounts must have to be able to log in at all; Every protected action is protected by this, at minimum.

That way, simply removing the "Login" role effectively disables the user... *because*, in my Roles Provider, I am checking the logged-in user's roles against the database or server-local equivalent.

In your case, your "Login" role could simply resolve to a check on the `IsApproved` field on your user model.

Comment: Is this a custom Roles provider? I'd like some more info, as this looks like a common problem.. I'm using a few different roles in my app but am not familiar with a role provider. I simply use the Roles.AddUserToRole method. Is there more to a role provider?

Comment: @CDSmith You can use the default roles provider and the relevant stuff in the aspnet database, and just require a basic "login" role for all protected activities. Only the last paragraph would require any custom provider.

Comment: So basically, as long as all my users belong to a role, and my disapproval functionality removes them from said role, they can no longer access protected actions, correct? Which is what I currently have

Comment: @CDSmith It occurs to me that I'm not 100% sure the default Roles provider works that way, now that you mention it. It might simply store the Roles in the ticket. I would verify by removing a required role and making a request, to make sure. I use a custom provider, myself.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense.. I just haven't gotten that far yet